# How to add a button in android?

Tags: android, button

Can anybody tell how to add a button in android?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I dynamically create a button in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011092/how-can-i-dynamically-create-a-button-in-android)

Answer (score 16):

Check this [Android Button](http://www.connorgarvey.com/blog/?p=93) tutorial; this simple example creates a Close Button.

All you need to do is:

1.Add Button widget to your Layout

```
<Button android:id="@+id/close"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="@string/title_close" />
```

2.Attach a setOnClickListener method to the button instance:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  this.setContentView(R.layout.layoutxml);
  this.closeButton = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.close);
  this.closeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      finish();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: hi,
is it possible to add a button without declaring it in the layout xml file?

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851633/how-to-add-button-dynamically-in-android

Answer (score 9):

**Dynamic:**

```
Button btn= new Button(this);  
btn.settext("Submit");  
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()   
{
    public void onClick(View view) 
     {
           //your write code
       }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to official documentation of [Buttons](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html) provided by Android.
You can first create Button in your `.xml` file.

**Button.xml**

```
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/button_text"
... />
```

And then cast your button with Button Class and set ClickListener.

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Do something in response to button click
}
  });
```

For further detail you can visit this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html)