# How can I dynamically create a button in Android?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to add button dynamically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851633/how-to-add-button-dynamically-in-android)

How can I dynamically create a button in Android?

Comment: DynamicAndroidButton button = new DynamicAndroidButton(); The only work remaining is implementing this class.

Comment: If you had any rep, you could put up bounty :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firstly add the appropriate *import* to your Activity:

```
import android.widget.Button;
```

Then create a new button object within the onCreate method:

```
Button myButton = new Button(this);
myButton.setText("Press Me");
```

Finally add the button to the layout:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
layout.addView(myButton);
```

Comment: How can I set its width to fill_parent? The setWidth method of the Button accepts only int.