# Add dynamic view in android

Tags: android, view

I want to create a view which has one button that add edit text and button to the view.
now how can i set the id to view so that i could also remove the view.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/q/3011092/964741

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whatever control you set I don't know but you can set the id of the control like this way

```
Button b; // if you want to set button and set the id 
b.setId(1);

View v;
v.setId(2);
```

or any control provide unique integer value

Comment: How can i save this id for removing view?

Comment: did you more explain how you can using your view? like multiple time or at specific time and why you want keep this id if the view was fixed and also id

Comment: You can see the android default Contact Manager Application in which when we add new contact then  it display a view for specifying phone type. i want to implement the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setId() function of View class which is inherited to most of views like TextView,Button...etc.

Comment: How can i save this id so that i can remove this view later on button click.

Answer (score 0):

when u create the dynamic button then only to set and get id from that like..

`int count = 0;`

`Button mbutton = new Button(getapplicationcontext());`

`mbutton.setId(count);`

`count++;`

when u want to perform the any action u want to get id from that like..

`mbutton.getId();`