# Sort buttons alphabetically

Tags: android, sorting, button

i created some buttons in an xml layout. They get their names from string resources in 3 different languages. Therefore the buttons aren't always in the correct alphabetical order. So there's my question. What can i do to make the buttons being sorted alphabetically in all 3 languages?

Sincerely
John

Comment: From XML file its not possible. You have to code it dynamically in your Activity.

Comment: you can create three different xml file and add in layout-<language-code> folder

Comment: Or make a 3 different layouts for different languages and at activity created time set according to current language. You can get language using Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();

Comment: @user370305 Yes, i assumed that, but how can i code it dynamically?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011092/how-can-i-dynamically-create-a-button-in-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851633/how-to-add-button-dynamically-in-android

Comment: @user370305 and neilmw Perfect, i think i can do it now. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: But best approach is use only one layout for buttons, and set its name according to alphabet on creation of activity using get current language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the three buttons are in a LinearLayout, you can subclass LinearLayout and override the getChildAt() method to return the Views in the order you want (which you could work out once the Strings are loaded).

E.g.

```
@Override
public View getChildAt(int index)
{
  // translate index into the ordering you want.
  // and put into newIndex...

  return super.getChildAt(newIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Layout for each language (check this [document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html))

Another solution is to load the strings in a `List`, sort them and then use `Button.setText` to set the strings of each button from the sorted `List` and `Button.setTag` to give each button a unique tag for this text. After that you can use the tag to set the `onClickListener` accordingly.