# Android draw a widget under certain circumstances

Tags: java, android

Is it possible in Android to draw a widget in an `Activity` only if a `boolean` value equals true? Basically, I'd like to hide a `Button` if the currently logged in user isn't an administrator, but display if they are.

Is something like this possible? I haven't noticed a widget property that could provide the functionality I seek, but I'm hoping I'm overseeing something. A less desirable alternative would be to create an Intent to a completely separate administrator focused `Activity`, and load an administrator specific layout.xml, but that immediately creates an significant amount of duplicate code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is android:visibility

You can set the value either to visible (self-explanatory), invisible (not visible but still takes up space in the layout, or gone (it's not included in the layout at all).

Relevant links:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:visibility

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851633/how-to-add-button-dynamically-in-android), it shows you how to add a button dynamically.

You can also take a look at [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). Fragments provide additional set of API to customize Activity by assembling fragments of UI and behavior. It might be a good choice if you decided to add whole lot of features to administrator. Using Fragments, your code will be cleaner, separating 'admin' UI components from the rest.