# How to create buttons from an activity dynamically

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to add button dynamically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851633/how-to-add-button-dynamically-in-android)

How to create dynamic UI for an activity? I should be able to add buttons by clicking add from the menu with desired name.

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851633/how-to-add-button-dynamically-in-android) out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the following code into the clickListener of your menu item

```
Button btn = new Button(this); 
btn.setText("myDynamicButton"); 
layout.addView(btn);
```

You can check the following links for further information

http://androidforums.com/application-development/35582-adding-buttons-dynamically.html

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/android-developers/Ut-Q_J75OoM/n9siUXldslEJ