# try to make note app but when i open activity no buttons are to see

Tags: android, sdk

i am trying to make a note app when i click on my Open note activity it should create a button array but it do not show any buttons

thats the code to initial the button array:

```
package savovuksan.at.noteit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class NotizOeffnungsMenue extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {


Button[] NoteListBtn ;
String[] NoteList ;





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notiz_oeffnungs_menue);

        NoteListBtn = new Button[fileList().length];
        NoteList = fileList();

    for (int i = 0;i<fileList().length;i++)
    {


        NoteListBtn[i] = new Button(this);
        NoteListBtn[i].setText(NoteList[i]);
        NoteListBtn[i].setOnClickListener(this);

    }
```

Comment: in your code edittext object is created but not added on to the view

Comment: See this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851633/how-to-add-button-dynamically-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add buttons in layout after you create them:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_notiz_oeffnungs_menue);
LinearLayout l1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
```

...

```
for (int i = 0;i<fileList().length;i++)
{
    NoteListBtn[i] = new Button(this);
    NoteListBtn[i].setText(NoteList[i]);
    NoteListBtn[i].setOnClickListener(this);
    l1.addView(NoteListBtn[i]);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you i am a beginner at android sdk i must learn but thats the reason why I write a note app thank you :)