# Getting information from an activity and adding a button to a fragment that has said information.

Tags: android, button

So a fragment on my Alarm application calls an activity and in the activity you set up information. My question is how can I take that information and create, lets say, a button that displays all that information. and how can I add that button to the fragment during runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm assuming you have `EditText`s that you're pulling the information from.

First, you'll want to pull that info. Making sure that you initialized your `TextView`s in the `onCreate()` method:

```
String thing1 = thingOneTextView.getText().toString();
String thing2 = thingTwoTextView.getText().toString();
String thing3 = thingThreeTextView.getText().toString();
```

Then, if you need to get this info back to your original activity (I'm not sure if you do - you weren't too clear on this in your original question), you'll want to use an `Intent` and `addExtra()`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OriginalActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("firstThing",thing1);
intent.putExtra("secondThing",thing2);
intent.putExtra("thirdThing",thing3);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then, in your original activity, in your `onCreate()`, you'll want to read this data in.

```
String thing1, thing2, thing3;

Intent intent = getIntent();
if(intent != null && intent.getStringExtra(firstThing") != null) {
    thing1 = intent.getStringExtra("firstThing","-1");
    thing2 = intent.getStringExtra("secondThing","-1");       
    thing3 = intent.getStringExtra("thirdThing","-1");
}
```

Now, to add the button. This is how you do it dynamically:

```
Button b = new Button(this);
b.setText(thing1 + " " + thing2 + " " + thing3);
LinearLayout linLay = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.my_linear_layout_from_the_xml);
LayoutParams layParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
linLay.addView(b, layParams);
```

You can read more about adding the button dynamically on [this great StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851633/how-to-add-button-dynamically-in-android).