# Creating a button dynamically with a user inputted title from different activity

Tags: java, android, button, android-studio, dynamically-generated

I'm trying to learn a little about android programming on the side, but I am still a beginner, so any help would be really appreciated, I'm sure this isn't too hard for someone with some experience.

What I want to do is be able to load up an activity, which originally just an "add button" button.

When the add button is clicked the page links to 3 user inputted strings (say str1, str2, str3).  I want to be able to click a button on this second activity and have the screen link back to the original activity, with a new button added displaying "str1 str2 str3" and the "add button" button underneath that new one.

I have managed to do the first part and have created all of the fields and the button on the 2nd activity, but I don't know how to go about creating the button back on the first activity dynamically and with the string desired.

Thank you all in advance!!

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851633/how-to-add-button-dynamically-in-android

Comment: @puj I have the button dynamically adding to the current page, but I cant get it to add a new button above the add button on the main screen once the second screen is submitted

Answer (score 0):

in your layout add a button

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="..."/>
```

and in your java try this:

```
Button mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
mButton.setTextSize(str1+str2+str3);
```

and for button click event:

```
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {

       //do what you want here

     }
   });
```

Comment: I have the button dynamically adding to the current page, but I cant get it to add a new button above the add button on the main screen once the second screen is submitted