# How to add a button in android studio

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add a button to my app in android studio, i followed a youtube video, but everytime I run it, it shuts down. I dont know why this happens, and have no idea how to get a button working. if anyone could help that would be great

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Draw draw;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);
        l.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        setContentView(l);
        l.addView(new Draw(this));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        draw = new Draw(this);
        draw.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        setContentView(draw);

        setUpBlockBtn();
    }

    private void setUpBlockBtn(){
        Button addBlockButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBlock);

        addBlockButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("DemoButtonApp", "you clicked the button");
                //finish();
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

Comment: put your logcat output here to know about error?. But may be it happen because you use  setContentView(l); two times.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add button dynamically in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851633/how-to-add-button-dynamically-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

you are using setContentView 3 times, why?? if you have defined button in *activity_main.xml* then use it as contentview. in your programm when you are calling *setUpBlockBtn()* to access Button object you have to set the correct contentview, in this case it should be *activity_main.xml*. again at line *setContentView(draw);* you are changing it that can not instantiate the button *findViewById(R.id.btnBlock);*  so you app is crashing. **in short set correct contentView**

Comment: Ok thanks, how do i do this though, i dont really understand what it does and how it works?

Comment: define button in activity_main.xml with id btnBlock.
and 

`@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button addBlockButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBlock);
        addBlockButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
 }`
google it for basic tutorials :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1- Creating a xml layout file with button in it:

create a new layout file as `activity_main` in res/layout directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  <Button 
      android:id="@+id/button"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Action!"
  />

</LinearLayout>
```

and use this layout in your Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        setUpButton();
    }

    private void setUpButton() {
        // Do something with your button
    }
}
```

2- Adding button dynamically to your Activity:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button = new Button(this);
        // set button's properties

        setContentView(button);
        setUpButton();
    }

    private void setUpButton() {
        // Do something with your button
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way to add a Button
Create a blank xml file
In the text add

```
<Button 
     android:id="@+id/button"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

This should create a button