# what's the benefit of using new Button(this)?

Tags: java, android

**ConditonA:**

```
//declare mybutton object and point to null;
Button mybutton ; 
//mybutton point to the instance of layout_button
mybutton = (Button)findViewByid(R.id.layout_button);
```

**CondtionB:**

```
//declare mybutton object and point to new Button object;
Button mybutton = new Button(this);
//mybutton repoint to the instance of layout_button
mybutton = (Button)findViewByid(R.id.layout_button);
// previous new Button(this) should be recycle??
```

Hi all
As above example , i found many sample code use Condition B ,but i don't know what's the benefit of it. Should it result in garbage???

Comment: Example B is wildly incorrect. Don't use it. You're creating UI elements that are never used.

Answer (score 2):

When called in an activity, "this" provides the current context, so it is the same thing as doing:

```
Button = new Button(getContext());
```

You can use this constructor when you're making a button from scratch. But if you've already declared your button in XML, you can just use `findViewByid(R.id.my_button_id_here)` instead, which will locate the button already defined in your XML. So in your second example there, you don't need the `new Button(this)`, because it is being overwritten by the `findViewByid` statement in the next line.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) you can see that Android uses `findViewByid` alone for buttons defined in XML.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851633/how-to-add-a-button-dynamically-in-android) you can see how the context constructor is used to create a button that is not defined in XML.

Comment: `findViewById` is not a constructor.

Comment: @323go that is true, I didn't realize I called it one. Fixed, thanks.