# Android: create an object (button) at runtime

Tags: android, object, runtime

im pretty new to Android Studio and I already did some research but didn't found a solution. I want to create an object (button) at runtime per Java. I already tried this:

In global:

```
Button btn;
```

In method:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
```

But this isn't working. So can somebody show me, how I can create a button at runtime and also how to change the attributes.

Thank You

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851633/how-to-add-a-button-dynamically-in-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a button dynamically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851633/how-to-add-a-button-dynamically-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findViewById` searches for layout elements by the `id` attribute. You don't have one on your button; you can't just use the variable name and expect it to work.

```
Button btn = new Button(this);
```

To add attributes:

```
btn.setText("My Button");
```

You will also need to add your button to the layout to get it to show up. In your layout XML, give your layout (`LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, etc.) an ID. Then:

```
mLayout = findViewById(R.id.layoutMain);
mLayout.addView(btn);
```

Comment: LinearLayout ll = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        ll.addView(btn, 2, 5);  I tried it like this, but isn't working, what am I doing wrong? And already thank you fo your good help :)