# android - dynamically adding a button to a custom dialogbox

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, dynamic

I am writing an android app,
I have an activity, inside it i have a button, and it's on click listener opens a dialog box from a custom XML using the following code:

I would like to add that dialog box another button that is not set in it's XML file.

All the components are excising in the XML and working just fine, the dialog opens but I can't add the b button.

```
this.addCheer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Dialog d = new Dialog(map.this);
                LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.dialog_layout_root);
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = d.getLayoutInflater();
                d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                d.setContentView(R.layout.cheer_dialog);// custom layout for the dialog
                WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
                lp.copyFrom(d.getWindow().getAttributes());
                lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                d.show();
                d.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
                final EditText title = d.findViewById(R.id.cheerDialogText);

                ImageButton addCheerOk = (ImageButton) d.findViewById(R.id.addCheerOk);

                Button b = new Button(d.getContext());
                b.setText("yo");

                cheerDialogLayout.addView(b, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
}
```

I tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851633/how-to-add-a-button-dynamically-in-android) example but it does not work for me. What am i doing wrong here? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try below code

```
this.addCheer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Dialog d = new Dialog(map.this);
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = d.getLayoutInflater();
                d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                d.setContentView(R.layout.cheer_dialog);// custom layout for the dialog

                WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
                lp.copyFrom(d.getWindow().getAttributes());
                lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                d.show();
                d.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

                LinearLayout layout = d.findViewById(R.id.dialog_layout_root);
                final EditText title = d.findViewById(R.id.cheerDialogText);

                ImageButton addCheerOk = (ImageButton) d.findViewById(R.id.addCheerOk);

                Button b = new Button(d.getContext());
                b.setText("yo");

                layout.addView(b, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
}
```

You were using only `findViewById(R.id.dialog_layout_root);` instead of `d.findViewById(R.id.dialog_layout_root);`

Comment: It did not work, layout came back as a null, it worked after i moved the d.findViewById() after the d.getWindow(). would you like to fix it, add some explenation and i'll accept the answer?

Comment: @thebeancounter I edited my answer and added explanation, you can now accept answer

Comment: Great, thanks, btw, when trying to add two buttons only one appear. how is that?

Comment: You have to set ids to your buttons. If code worked then please accept and up vote answer so others can trust and use this code.

Comment: no problem, could you please add the code for the id's?

Comment: Just do  b.setId(i)    //Where i is any integer number

Comment: I've set the id and i still can only add one button, no other button gets added. could you add an example for adding two buttons?

Comment: Did you use two different ids for buttons

Answer (score 0):

Here ll_button is the id of layout which contains the two xml buttons you have.

```
LinearLayout ll_button = d.findViewById(R.id.ll_button);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new inearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
ll_button.addView(b, layoutParams);
```

Remove your last line.

```
cheerDialogLayout.addView(b, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```