# Building a variable upon buttons to trigger listeners

Tags: java, android, android-button

I am breaking my head dealing with variables types in my app.
I try in a loop to increase a var and pass it to a listener, according to the name of the buttons defined in my XML layout.
I would like to start from "jeton1" to "jeton2","jeton3"...., but cannot manage to do that in my code (errors arising), the vars do not point to the `buttons` stored in the `XML` and not showing up when calling the `buttons` listeners.
I made a test with a defined array but the stuff failed.
Test code below made upon only one `button`. 
A help would be greatly appreciated.

**Here is my code
The XML layout :**

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:rowCount="20"
    android:columnCount="9">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/jeton1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:text="@string/boutona"
        android:layout_height="88dp"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:backgroundTint="#eeceac"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

**Main Java :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int i;
String jeton = "";

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Main loop

    for (i = 1; i < 2; i++) {

        jeton = "jeton" + i; // Should throw "jeton1", "jeton2".....
        final Button jetonnew;
        jetonnew = (Button) findViewById(R.id.jeton); // Error 'cannot resolve symbol

        // jetonnew = (Button)findViewById(R.id.jeton+i);
        // Step 4 Listener

        jetonnew.setOnTouchListener(
                new View.OnTouchListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

                        switch (event.getAction()) {

                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                                jetonnew.getBackground().setAlpha(0); // Crash app
                                jetonnew.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2aa17b"));
                                break;
                        }
                        return true;
                    }

                });
    }
}
```

}

Many thanks for your replies and suggestions.

Comment: I don't get your question fully? Do you want to build buttons dynamically? If yes, have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851633/how-to-add-a-button-dynamically-in-android

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fixed number of buttons, you can store an array of integers

```
  int[] ids = {R.id.button1, R.id.button2, ...};
```

However, if you want to dynamically add buttons, you should try creating them programmatically

```
Button newButton = new Button(this);
```

or you can create some custom layout and inflate it

```
inflate(this, R.layout.customLayout, null);
```

Keep in mind that R.id.someId returns and integer not a string so you cannot append to it. Also adding a string after id does not work for the same reason.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried the array method but it did not work.

Comment: @alhambra60 you should use the ints in the findViewById() method. eg. findViewById(ids[i]);

Answer (score 0):

> jetonnew = (Button)findViewById(R.id.jeton+i);

This portion of code does not work because `R.id.jeton` is a generated integer not a string.

You should consider using [findViewByTag](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=android.view.ViewGroup&method=findViewWithTag) instead of findViewById. Your code will look like this:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:rowCount="20"
android:columnCount="9">

<Button
    android:tag="jeton1"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:text="@string/boutona"
    android:layout_height="88dp"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:backgroundTint="#eeceac"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

So in your java file:

```
for (i = 1; i < 2; i++) {

    jeton = "jeton" + i; // Should throw "jeton1", "jeton2".....
    final Button jetonnew;
    //findViewByTag here
    jetonnew = (Button) findViewByTag(jeton)
```

Another way is to just iterate through GridLayout child, like this:

```
//suppose your gridLayout has id=@+id/gridparent
GridLayout gridParent = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.gridparent);
for(int index=0; index<gridParent.getChildCount(); ++index) {
     Button nextButton = (Button)gridParent.getChildAt(index);
     //attach listener here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the id of the button by using its name:

```
jetonnew = findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("jeton" + i, "id", getPackageName()));
```

Comment: Thank you mTak, I tried this one and it worked fine.

Comment: @alhambra60 I'm glad, just accept the answer as the right one

Answer (score 0):

You should create arrays of your grid button id's.

```
@IntegerRes int [] resourceButtonIds = new int[]{R.id.jeton1,R.id.jeton2};
```

Then modify the loop accordingly.

```
    for (i = 0; i < resourceButtonIds.length; i++) {
       final Button jetonnew;
       jetonnew = (Button) findViewById(resourceButtonIds[i]); 
       // now set all your listeners
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Krishna, I tried this but for any reason it did not work.

Comment: @alhambra60 didn't work means what ? errors are still there while calling findViewById ?. Can you please explain in details what issue you facing after using the solution I proposed.