# Incompatible types: Widget cannot be converted to Context

Tags: java, android, cordova, widget, android-widget

I am developing widget and I am trying to dynamically add button to my LinearLayout. I am trying to use code from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851633/how-to-add-a-button-dynamically-in-android).

```java
Button myButton = new Button(this);
myButton.setText("Push Me");

LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.widget_layout);
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
ll.addView(myButton, lp);
```

The problem is that I get this error:

```java
error: incompatible types: Widget cannot be converted to Context
        Button myButton = new Button(this);
                                     ^
```

Do you know what is the problem here?
My widget class:

```java
package com.fxteam.malcome;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.Button;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import android.util.Log;

public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private static final String SYNC_CLICKED    = "malcome_widget_button";

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            intent2.putExtra("accountID", "0");
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent2, 0);
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.simple_app_widget);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.malcome_widget_button, pendingIntent);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }



        Button myButton = new Button(this);
        myButton.setText("Push Me");

        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.widget_layout);
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ll.addView(myButton, lp);
    }
}
```

All errors:

```
BUILD FAILED in 1s
(node:660) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
C:\Users\Adam\cordova\widget\malcomeWidget\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\fxteam\malcome\Widget.java:47: error: incompatible types: Widget cannot be converted to Context
        Button myButton = new Button(this);
                                     ^
C:\Users\Adam\cordova\widget\malcomeWidget\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\fxteam\malcome\Widget.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.widget_layout);
                                        ^
  symbol:   method findViewById(int)
  location: class Widget
C:\Users\Adam\cordova\widget\malcomeWidget\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\fxteam\malcome\Widget.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ^
  symbol:   class LayoutParams
  location: class Widget
C:\Users\Adam\cordova\widget\malcomeWidget\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\fxteam\malcome\Widget.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                              ^
  symbol:   class LayoutParams
  location: class Widget
C:\Users\Adam\cordova\widget\malcomeWidget\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\fxteam\malcome\Widget.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                           ^
  symbol:   variable LayoutParams
  location: class Widget
C:\Users\Adam\cordova\widget\malcomeWidget\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\fxteam\malcome\Widget.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                                                      ^
  symbol:   variable LayoutParams
  location: class Widget
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\Adam\cordova\widget\malcomeWidget\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\file\AssetFilesystem.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
6 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Adam\cordova\widget\malcomeWidget\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
(node:660) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:660) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I apologize for so much code in this question, but I want it to be as detailed as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have passed `Widget` instance instead of Activity `context` to create `Button`.

Use

```
Button myButton = new Button(context);
```

Instead of

```
Button myButton = new Button(this);
```

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem, but still i get 5 more. Do you know how to solve
 cannot find symbol
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                                                      ^
  symbol:   variable LayoutParams

Comment: ok the problem was i didnt import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;

Comment: Last thing: cannot find symbol findViewById: LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.widget_layout);